# SVD/Matlab. Function that takes matrix as input, calculates svd, returns approximation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Input is supposed to be a mxn matrix and a natural number k so that 0

I started with this code

```
function AK = svdapprox(A,k)
tol=0.001                                   
r=rank(A,tol)
if k>r           % return error message if k exceeds rank of matrix          
        fprintf('Value of k must not exceed that of r' ); 
end
[U, S, V]=svd(A)             %calculate the svd of a
```

To proceeed from here, I was thinking since number of singular values in s=rank A, i could limit the diagnoal  of s to k elements and then make it return u*s*v, but i couldn't find a way to make this work. As you can see I don't have much experience with matlab and I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Details and examples of low rank approximations are in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138119/interpretation-of-svd-for-text-mining-topic-analysis/2275599#2275599, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205651/low-rank-approximation-with-svd-on-a-kernel-matrix/2207592#2207592

Answer (score 1):

You want the first $k$ columns of $U$, the upper $k \times k$ part of $S$, and the first $k$ rows of $v$.

For this you want

```
 u = U(1:k, :)
 s = S(1:k, 1:k)
 v = V(:, 1:k)
```

Comment: IIRC Matlab gives V with the right singular vectors as columns, so you want those columns of V followed by a transpose or those rows of V'.